# Field length for BIT data type field to indicate yes/no?

Tags: mysql, sqldatatypes

I am wanting to use the `BIT` data type to indicate Yes/No / True/False conditions

Should I assign a length in this case of 1 to the field? Is it necessary?

`BIT` seems to be a bit of a special data type – pun not intended (but left in)

Answer (score 3):

I would strongly advise using the `boolean` datatype for a boolean value - its meaning is clear, queries will be easier to write and later read, and code using the value will be simpler and cleaner.

Attempting to "save disk space" or other premature optimizations by using exotic datatypes is foolish: Use the appropriate datatype and let the database engine take care of micro-optimisations.

Comment: I read that tinyint and boolean are the same thing in MySQL, can you elaborate on the use of boolean?

Comment: @Drewdavid mysql's *implementation* of `boolean` is TINYINT, and in *mysql* they are (currently) synonymous, but TINYINT is a mysql-only (afaik) datatype and the *portable*, or canonical, datatype - globally understood by databases snd the community, is `boolean`, so I believe that's the better choice.